# How can I plot a meshgrid in Matlab with empty gridsquares (i.e. showing the gridlines)

Tags: matlab, plot

I am using meshgrid to create matrices of coordinates to plot model output within gridded data of Europe.The dataset is 106 x 103 and everywhere there is no data, the value is set to NaN.

```
[meshlat,meshlon]=meshgrid(rlat,rlon);
surf(meshlon,meshlat,data(:,:,1)),'linestyle','none';view(2);
```

[image]

But I actually want all the grid squares that don't have output to be plotted too (so the extra ones that are in this map, comprising Scandinavia..but I want them to be white):

[image]

I'm thinking that I may need to create a third matrix the same size as the meshlat and meshlon and fill it with a number that would correspond to the colour white...plot it, then type 'hold', and plot my map on top? I'm not sure how to specify the white colour though? Or is there another way of doing it?

Here is a simplified version of the problem:

```
data = magic(4);
data(1,2) = nan;
x = [1,2,3,4];
lat = repmat(x,4,1);
lon = lat';
surf(lon,lat,data);view(2);
```

You can see the blank space on the left..In this example, I would like to see extra grid lines where the squares would be (if there were no nans in the dataset)

When I tried @Hoki's suggestion, I ended up with grid squares around every 'cell' in the matrix...whether it was filled with a number or a NaN (below) which is not what I originally needed. I wanted just the land masses (that have real numbers, not NaNs to have a gridline around them):
[image]

By using the full dataset (in the first image), I plotted the outline of the gridsquares for the landmasses using:

```
surf(meshlon,meshlat,fulldata(:,:,1),'FaceColor','none','EdgeColor','k');view(2);
```

Then I plotted my 'coloured' grid squares over that original dataset:

```
hold on;
surf(meshlon,meshlat,data(:,:,1)),'linestyle','none';view(2);
```

Using the simplified example below, the code is:

```
data = magic(4);
datafull=data;
data(1,2) = nan;
x = [1,2,3,4];
lat = repmat(x,4,1);
lon = lat';
surf(lon,lat,datafull,'FaceColor','none','EdgeColor','k');view(2);
hold on
surf(lon,lat,data);view(2);
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to contain your code and sample input-data, this is called a [mcve]. This will make it a lot easier to answer, since now it's unclear why this problem presents itself. My hunch is that you have `NaN` values in Scandinavia; setting them to white (RGB `[1 1 1]`) could work then.

Comment: When they have "no output" what is their value in `data`? Also, if you have `'linestile','none'`, you shoudl not be able to see the black lines. Please provide the real example

Comment: @Adriaan My code is enormous (495 lines) with function I have built buried in it. I do have Nan values where there is no model output (as you correctly ascertained), which I modified in my question. I am going to try and upload the matrices now.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: That is the exact code I used to produce the images I have uploaded.

Comment: @matlab_newby you don't have to provide the full code that creates the figure that you showed... Instead, try to provide some code that generates a small example - even something as simple as `m = magic(4); m(10) = NaN; meshgrid...`), as long as it illustrates your problem and is **self-contained**.

Comment: thanks @Dev-iL.I've done that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve the result you want. The "cleaner" and less memory hungry way is unfortunately quite more complex than the simple workaround.

**Method 1** *(not recommended, and not detailed ...)*

- You need to create a special colormap with a "white" color at one end (min or max), making sure that the value that will map to this color are **not** in your data.
- Before you plot your data, for all the pixels for Scandinavia (or any pixel which doesn't have a value but where you want to see your grid) replace the `NaN` by the value which will map to the white in the colormap.

As you can see, this method will force you to re-evaluate your colormap for each new dataset, so not very flexible.

**Method 2** *(Recommended, more generic ...)*
Just create an empty 'grid' exactly how you want it, then display it on top of your surface plot. This grid will be transparent so it can be used on top of any dataset.

For your example:

```
%% Your example
data = magic(4);
data(1,2) = nan;
x = [1,2,3,4];
lat = repmat(x,4,1);
lon = lat';
surf(lon,lat,data);view(2);


%% The overlay grid:
% Create a grid the same size of the data. We set the Z value to the max of
% the original data set to make sure the grid will be "on top" of the
% surface plot when view from above.
datagrid = ones(size(data))*max(data(:)) ;
% plot the grid on top of the previous surface plot
hold on
hm = mesh(lon,lat,datagrid,'FaceColor','none','EdgeColor','k') ;
```

This is what you'll get. The second figure on the right is the same with a different view so you understand what is going on on the `Z` dimension.

With a reference grid like that, you can overlay it on any of your dataset, regardless of which areas have been blanked/nullified.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it hasn't exactly done what I wanted. I understand why it isn't doing it..The grid is based on a size that isn't what I want (see edited question above for output map). I need to find a way to create this 'overlay' only for the cells in the matrix that have actual numbers in them..not NaNs.

Comment: I used your idea though and have made it work (in question above). Many thanks

Comment: Yes, you have to trim your base grid to only the landmass or only the grid points/lines you want to appear, but the idea is once it is done you can always reuse the same base grid. To generate it (to know where to add the proper `NaN` to your base grid) you can do it based on your second dataset (second picture on your example), which seem to contain all the landmass you want.